# avoiding multiple register() calls with phonegap PushPlugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

The [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) plugin for push notifications for mobile apps seems to only let you set the callback to be used via a call to `register`. But this potentially means that the app will re-register with Google (or whoever) every time the app is opened, whereas Google's sample code and documentation suggests that registration should happen fairly rarely---on app install or version changes, for instance. (And since it would require a round trip to Google's servers and then to my own, it seems wise to minimize it anyway.)

Is there a way to avoid this seemingly pointless re-registration?

Answer (score 1):

please see this solution 
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/287/files

just some modification on the plugin file and you will get the result.

after doing the modification...
In your html page where you need to just listen to the notification without registration, you have to call this (after device ready):

```
var pushNotification;
pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.setupCallbacks(
    SuccessHandler,
    errorHandler,
    {
        "senderID":"yoursenderID",
        "ecb":"onNotification"
    });
function SuccessHandler(result){
    console.log("Active On Notification without register ==================================");
    console.log(result);
}
function errorHandler(error){
}
```

that helped me in the same issue.